# Recompute distances after node removal

Tags: algorithm

I have a graph with computed distances from the "start" node. Now I'd like to remove one node (except the starting one) and recompute distances (ideally without running Shortest Path First on the whole graph).

I don't know how to google such an algorithm and my attempts seem to be quite complicated (especially when compared to adding a new node).

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement Dijkstra's algorithm is to maintain a set of nodes whose distance from the start needs to be updated. When a node's distance is effectively updated, that node is removed from the set, but all of its neighbours are added to the set. When a node's update has no effect, *i.e.*, when that node's distance doesn't change, the node is removed from the set and no node is added. The halting condition for the algorithm is "no node needs to be updated".

When you remove a node from the graph, all of its neighbours need to be updated to reflect the removal.

So you can simply "relaunch" Dijkstra's algorithm on your graph, with the initial distances from the start node which you already have, and with the set of nodes to be updated initialised with the neighbours of the node that was removed. The updates will naturally propagate to any node that will eventually need to be updated.

Note: If your graph is oriented, only the nodes with an incoming edge from the removed node need to be added to the set of nodes to be updated.

Comment: "remove a node from the graph, all of its neighbours need to be updated" - not only its neighbors; potentially, the whole graph will need to be updated. See the second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: @tucuxi: It propagates indeed. That's how Dijkstra's algorithm works. But not necessarily to the whole graph. A node only needs to be updated if one of its incoming neighbours has been updated.

Comment: You are right. I have updated my answer with the resulting algorithm; and also, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to [@Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080723/stef), whose [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64496740/15472) I am now extending.

Removing a node that is part of a set of minimal paths may require recalculation of *all* distances to their end-nodes. Using the pseudocode from Dijkstra's algorithm as found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm):

```
 1  function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:            
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                 
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                
 8          add v to Q                     
10      dist[source] ← 0                       
11     
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]   
14                                             
15          remove u from Q
16         
17          for each neighbor v of u:           // only v that are still in Q
18              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
19              if alt < dist[v]:              
20                  dist[v] ← alt
21                  prev[v] ← u
22
23      return dist[], prev[]
```

the `prev` array contains the previous node to each node in the minimum spanning tree (= the tree of all shortest paths). So, to remove node `r`, assuming you still have the `dist` and `prev` array from before removal, you could change it to:

```
 function DijkstraRemove(Graph, dist, prev, removed):
 
        create vertex set Q
 
        for each vertex v in Graph:            
           while (prev[v] != UNDEFINED):
               if prev[v] == removed: 
                  add v to Q
                  dist[v] = UNDEFINED
                  prev[v] = UNDEFINED
                  break
               else:
                  v = prev[v]

        // continue with line 12 above
```